# Can the Facebook SDK support sharing from any website?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I am creating a website that will allow users to embed widgets on their own blogs and websites. I have previously used the Facebook SDK to allow URLs to be shared from defined websites, but now I need this to work for *any* website. However, when creating a Facebook app "App domains" have to be specified/whitelisted and I can't see how to bypass this restriction. Can anybody help please?

```
FB.init({
    appId            : 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    autoLogAppEvents : true,
    xfbml            : true,
    version          : 'v3.3'
});
FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    display: 'popup',
    href: url,
}, function(response){});
```

Comment: Do you need other Facebook functionality in your widgets, anything related to logging users in/asking for permissions? If not, you could let people use their own app ids for their specific websites.

Comment: No, it is only used for sharing. I think allowing them to use their own App IDs may be the only option, unfortunately.